# running process in backround using a bash script

Tags: bash, process, fork, sh

I want run a script as follows:

runner:
ssh  'java program &'
ssh  'java program &'

How do I write the script to fork the first process? Currently, it waits for it to finish.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I think you want

```
ssh -f -n remotesystem 'command&'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your script:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh yourhost 'java program &' &
ssh yourhost 'java program &'
```

The first ssh will start a session running a java program in the background. If the java program is a graphical application and you are running with port forwarding enabled the ssh process will still continue running even after the command `java program &` is finished. By adding the final `&` to the first command line the ssh program will be put running in the background.